# Get HTTP response code from JAX-WS asynchronous web service

Tags: java, web-services, http, jax-ws, response

I have an asynchronous JAX-WS web service (`@WebService` and `@WebMethod` annotations). I am invoking it in Java. and I would like to know how to get HTTP response code from that service in Java code.

Comment: JAX-WS is simply communicating SOAP messages in HTTP transport layer. The same way you would get the response code from a HTTP response is the way to go.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I thought about that, but couldn't find any solution. Anyway, I have found a solution, see my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on that subject, but I deduced solution based on how my request context is built, because I needed response context so I thought they may be similar. Request context:

`((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint)`

So I thought that this may work:

`int responseCode = (int)((BindingProvider) port).getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);`

And it works. ; )