# How to get JAX-WS response HTTP status code

Tags: java, jax-ws

When calling a JAX-WS endpoint, how can I get the HTTP response code?

In the sample code bellow, when calling the web service at `port.getCustomer(customerID);` an Exception may be thrown, such as `401` or `500`.

In such cases, how can I get the HTTP status code from the HTTP response?

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerWSClient {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "/customer.wsdl")
    private CustomerService service;

    public void getCustomer(Integer customerID) throws Exception {
        Customer port = service.getCustomerPort();
        port.getCustomer(customerID); // how to get HTTP status           
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to capture the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing @Praveen answer, you have to turn the `port` into a raw `BindingProvider` and then get the values from the context.

Don't forget that transaction will be marked for rollback if an exception occours in your managed web service client.

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerWSClient {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "/customer.wsdl")
    private CustomerService service;

    public void getCustomer(Integer customerID) throws Exception {
        Customer port = service.getCustomerPort();
        try {
            port.getCustomer(customerID);  
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            // Get the HTTP code here!
            int responseCode = (Integer)((BindingProvider) port).getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below post is similar to your question. Hopefully it should work for you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914837/4896191

Comment: It works perfectly, not sure how I didn't run into it after searching a lot. Guess I do not know as much of JAX-WS as I thought.