# wsimport - How to get HTTP status code from response to verify

Tags: java, soap, webservice-client, wsimport

I am using wsimport to create java classes from a WSDL and test Soap request. So far I am able to get raw request and response successfully but couldn't find a method to get the http status code.
Is there a class method exposed to print the same?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43670704/455814

Comment: Unfortunately i couldn't find the solution anywhere. It worked like a charm. Thanks @Waqas